# Are my arrays incompatible?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to loop through an array that contains split strings, done via this line:
`repHolder() = Split(rep, ",")`

That's all fine and good, however, when I try to loop through this `repHolder()` array via a `for` loop, I am met each time with a `subscript out of range` error.

This makes no sense to me. When I step through the array it fails on the first element every time; this line:

`If repHolder(j) = counter Then`

I tried setting `j` to 0 and 1, both of which failed on the first sequence of the loop. This suggests to me because the array doesn't have a defined size; that I cannot loop through it this way, but that still makes little sense to me as it is still filled with elements.

Here is the entire code block of what I am trying to do:

```
Dim repHolder() As String
Dim strHolder() As String
Dim counter As Variant
Dim j As Integer


For Each rep In repNames()

    repHolder() = Split(rep, ",")

Next rep



For Each rangeCell In repComboRange
k = 1

Do

If rangeCell.Value = repCombos(k) Then  'At this point, if rangecell = repcombos(k)

Range(rangeCell, rangeCell.End(xlToRight)).Copy
strHolder() = Split(rangeCell.Value, "/")

    For Each counter In strHolder()
        Stop
        For j = 1 To 17

            If repHolder(j) = counter Then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through `repNames()` and setting this new array via split (over and over again for each repName element...)

```
 For Each rep In repNames()    
    repHolder() = Split(rep, ",")    
 Next rep
```

Every iteration of this loop resets `repHolder()` to a split of the `rep` element dropping whatever values were just set in that array in the previous iteration. So once it's done only the last element of `RepNames()` has been split into the `repHolder()` array.

For instance, if `RepNames()` looks like:

```
Element 0: "james,linda,mahesh,bob"
Element 1: "rajesh,sam,barb,carrie"
Element 2: ""
```

Then after all this iterating your `repHolder` array is going to be empty because there is nothing in the final element.

Stick a breakpoint (F9) on you `For Each rangeCell In repComboRange` line and look at your Locals pane in VBE. Check out the values that are stored in your `repHolder()` array at that point in time. I suspect there will be nothing in there.

The other oddball here is that you are looping 1 through 17. `repHolder()` will be a 0-based array so that should be 0 through 16. But... even that is nonsense since this really only makes sense as a For Each loop (or to use the `uBound(repHolder)` to determine how many times to loop:

```
For Each counter In strHolder()
    Stop
    For each repHolderElem in repHolder
        If repHolderElem = counter Then
        ....
    Next repHolderElem
```

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea I kept deleting the previous element in the array